# Why does my modal view cause a "is not a constructor error"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to call a modal view inside another file and I am getting a "is not a constructor" error. My modal component looks like:

ModalView.js:

```
  export default class ModalView extends Modal {
  constructor() {
     super(onClose => {});

     this.setNoMaxHeight(false);
     this.setWidthPercentage(0.4);
 }

 closeModal = () => {
    this.close();
 };

 renderContent() {
    return <ModalContent closeModal={this.closeModal} />;
  }
}
```

The file I am calling it from looks like:

Product.js:

```
require(
   [
      'lego/component//ModalView'
],

function({ ModalView }) {
  events: {
    'click #apply': 'apply',
  },
  modalView: function () {
    new ModalView().render();
  }
```

I am rendering the modal view in react files using ".render()" in other places so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

In **Product.js** you're calling *.render()* when it is not defined on your **ModalView** component.

I'm assuming your intention is to call .*renderContext()*

Comment: How are you returning the JSX then? Also, can you refer me to where super accepts callback functions? This could also be the problem, try removing the anonymous function argument in super().

Comment: Yeah the problem was the export default with coordination with the require